# What is the difference between Chapati and a Paratha?

Tags: indian-cuisine

I have heard of folding a chapati dough while kneading to form a triangle. How is it different from not folding it? How does folding to a triangle and rolling a chapati makes the difference?

Comment: Where does the Paratha come into your question? You only mention it in the title.

Comment: I have read that Paratha is something where we apply oil and make a layer while rolling it, whereas we do not apply oil while rolling a chapati. How does applying oil and folding the dough to a traingle while rolling affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapathi or Roti is made from wheat flour usually in all of the Indian homes. Chapathi is usually bigger in size than Phulka. both sides are cooked on pan. Some people apply oil/ghee after completely cooking it but when it is not on the pan but while eating. Roti / chapati is usually not made to swell up, especially if it is rolled comparatively thick. Bubbles do appear in the roti / chapati when steam forms in some places. The word 'Roti' is used commonly in north, central and east India, whereas 'Chapati' is used more in west (Mumbai), and south India. Only in south India Chapati is fried in a bit of oil! Elsewhere, only a Paratha is fried with oil or ghee

Paratha is something which can be stuffed paratha or non stuffed paratha. Stuffed parartha is like Aloo Paratha, Methi Paratha and it is cooked on a pan too but oil/ghee/butter is applied while cooking on a pan. Non stuffed paratha is you make a puree of spinach or fenugreek with different spices and add it while preparing the dough itself. And then it is cooked on pan. Paratha (plain, folded or stuffed) is made from an unleavened dough of wholewheat flour, and shallow fried with a little oil / ghee / butter. Parathas generally stay soft and moist even when cold.

Yes, certainly sometimes meaning differs with context to people and region, though there may not  be much difference in preparing it.Triangle Shape has nothing to do with the Taste or Texture, it deals more with Presentation. Oil indeed influences the flavor & texture of dough. The "moistness" of the Parathas - the soft texture - is actually from oils and fats. Adding in extra fat, such as oil, butter, shortening, makes the Parathas seem extra moist and soft .

Answer (score 3):

Chapati or roti -> Made by folding dough and making a triangle shape results in 3 layered indian bread. If you tear the chapati made this way it will show you 3 layers.

Fulka -> Fulka is made by rolling the dough ball without folding it. This results into a 2 layer indian bread. Its easier to make a circle shape using this method.

Paratha -> Paratha is generally stuffed with some filling. There is plain paratha also (without filling). If it is stuffed , it is not folded into triangle during preparation. If it is plain paratha, it can be made either folding or just rolling (like fulka).

Oil added while kneading dough/ making chapati (folding) / while roasting on tawa ,  helps to keep the product soft.